# SQL Developer Error in ORACLE

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having issues with setting up SQL Developer. I have SQL Plus and have created a few tables that I would like to connect to with SQL Developer. Is this possible?
I have tried to set-up a connection in SQL Developer but no luck. I have looked up multiple threads on this and nothing seems to work. Many of the tutorials said to connect with HR_ORCL, hr for username and password. Below are some screenshots for the errors:
[Screenshot Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uF9N.png)

Comment: Looks like SQL Developer can't see the same tnsnames file as is used by SQL*Plus

Comment: @scott Is there a way can I change this or do some configs?

Comment: When I run lsnrctl status orcl I receive: TNS-01101: Could not find service name